# Unable to access Citrix XenApp 6 published applications externally

Tags: citrix, xenapp

We are trying to use a trial of Citrix XenApp 6 Fundamentals to virtualise a couple of applications as a proof of concept. We haven't ever used it before so I confess to be a noob with it.

We can connect to the XenApp web interface, and the iPad app will connect and list the applications, but the applications themselves will not load. I discovered in the .ica file that it was attempting to connect to the internal IP address of the server instead of its static external.

I have been following various threads on Citrix but nothing seems to have fixed it for me. The server is deployed on an EC2 instance with a static elastic IP. All the ports are opened and I can telnet into the XenApp server on 1493 and I get the ICA response. I have also run on ALTADDR and provided the external IP address.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue today. I know it's been a while since you posted, but were you ever able to figure this out? Citrix's documentation is lacking to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure the web interface Secure Access setting to "alternate" mode, so it actually uses the IP addresses you assigned with ALTADDR.